# Why is a lambda expression breaking guice error handling when i try to start jetty?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, guice, guice-3

I face the following problem where i try to start jetty, i get the following exeption:

```
Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51966
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4RunListener.rethrowAnyTestMechanismFailures(JUnit4RunListener.java:206)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:114)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:85)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:54)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51966
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.TestSet.replay(TestSet.java:100)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.ConcurrentRunListener.testSetCompleted(ConcurrentRunListener.java:82)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreRunListener.testRunFinished(JUnitCoreRunListener.java:73)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$2.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:95)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:61)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestRunFinished(RunNotifier.java:92)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:161)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:113)
[ERROR] ... 6 more
[ERROR] Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51966
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements.forMember(StackTraceElements.java:53)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatInjectionPoint(Errors.java:716)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:678)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.format(Errors.java:555)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.CreationException.getMessage(CreationException.java:48)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
[ERROR] at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979)
[ERROR] at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:754)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Throwable.java:764)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:655)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:721)
[ERROR] at org.junit.runner.notification.Failure.getTrace(Failure.java:71)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4StackTraceWriter.writeTraceToString(JUnit4StackTraceWriter.java:57)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.encode(ForkingRunListener.java:330)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.encode(ForkingRunListener.java:312)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.toString(ForkingRunListener.java:258)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.testError(ForkingRunListener.java:132)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.TestMethod.replay(TestMethod.java:118)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.TestSet.replay(TestSet.java:87)
[ERROR] ... 14 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51966
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.readUTF8(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.util.$LineNumbers.<init>(LineNumbers.java:62)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements$1.apply(StackTraceElements.java:36)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements$1.apply(StackTraceElements.java:33)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
[ERROR] ... 36 more
```

From what i've read the problem seems that lambdas break guice error handling, but still people haven't come up with a solution.
If someone knows what this is about please post comment!

Comment: show us your code that you're trying to run

Comment: You may need to upgrade to Guice 4 beta if you insist on using lambda. I would stick with the stable release and not use lambda: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice40

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This unreadable exception occurs when you have a bad configuration in one of your guice modules and you are using Java 8 lambdas and guice 3.

I have spent a lot of time with this issue. Each time, I solved the problem by upgrading to [guice 4](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice40) beta. One of its features is:

> Better Java8 runtime compatibility

If you use maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
  <version>4.0-beta5</version>
</dependency>
```

This new version will give you a clear error message and a proper stacktrace that will let you find the problem. When you have solved it, you can switch back to guice 3.0 or continue to using the 4.0-beta (which is - from what I've seen - already stable).

---

Edited the 2016/07/13

Note that [guice 4.0 and 4.1 have been released](https://github.com/google/guice/releases). So you should use the latest release:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Be advised if you're on a later JDK: On JDK 15, I was running into the same issue on Guice 4.2.3. An upgrade to 5.0.0-BETA-1 solved it.

Comment: Be advised, I _thought_ I was on Guice 4.2.3, but when I still got the error after upgrading to Guice 5.1.0 I realized another part of the system (Spark) was actually pulling in Guice 3.0. (My solution was to shade Guice _and_ Guava. This is horrible.)