# Guice 3.0 - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on startup?

Tags: guice-3

Why Guice 3.0 throws this exception instead of a formatted message for wrong configurated components (@Inject is missing for example)?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16640
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements.forMember(StackTraceElements.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatInjectionPoint(Errors.java:716)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:678)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.format(Errors.java:555)
    at com.google.inject.ConfigurationException.getMessage(ConfigurationException.java:70)
    at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
    at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2982)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println(Throwable.java:748)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:655)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:643)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:634)
    at hu.daniel.hari.exercises.cleanarchitecture.payrollcasestudy.adapters.primary.ui.impl.swing._2.SwingUIMain2.<init>(SwingUIMain2.java:40)
    at hu.daniel.hari.exercises.cleanarchitecture.payrollcasestudy.adapters.primary.ui.impl.swing._2.SwingUIMain2.main(SwingUIMain2.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16640
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$LineNumbers.<init>(LineNumbers.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements$1.apply(StackTraceElements.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements$1.apply(StackTraceElements.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 17 more
```

My initating code is:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new SwingUIModule(useCaseFactory));
injector.getInstance(MainFrameUI.class).show();
```

Comment: Did you found a solution? Any clue about the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is with how Guice 3 and below handles lambda expressions. You might have to upgrade to Guice 4 to fix this as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244342/why-is-a-lambda-expression-breaking-guice-error-handling-when-i-try-to-start-jet).

Answer (score 9):

We have faced this issue and **it turned out that it is not Guice 3 issue** at all (in our case). Fact is, though, that due to poor `Exception` handling in Guice 3 we got the same error message as the author.

### TL/DR

The source of our problem was `NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ...` exception that was thrown in a **static** block in one of our classes.

It turned out, that we had **excluded** too many classes during fat-jar building, and simply there were some classes missing. Unfortunately, with Guice 3, we received only `$ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: ...` message, to help us out.

**My point is, that it might be, that Guice 3 is not the source of your problem**.

### Full version

1. We have a project (A) that we include as a dependency in project (B) that is running on Spark Cluster
2. Project A, was using `log4j 2`, and `spark-hive` (used in Project B) for some reason does not like when it has extra logging frameworks in the classpath, so we excluded it in `sbt-assembly`:

   ```
   ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging.log4j"),
   ```
3. In project A, we have a class that has, lets say some code like this (java):

   ```
   static {
       this.defaultMarker = MarkerManager.getMarker("abc")
   }
   ```

   And `MarkerManager` is from `org.apache.logging.log4j`, so this class is missing in fat-jar of project B.
4. We run it on the cluster, where some class that is supposed to be `@injected` uses the class with static block.
5. Boom! `$ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
6. I decided to initialize all classes manually, without `Guice` only to find out that it was not `Guice` fault.
7. Fix the `ExclusionRule` and it all works with Guice 3 again.

Comment: Any tips for how to get hold of the real exception? Unfortunately Guice is not in my code but in a dependency, so I can't easily try without it.

Comment: As I have put in the answer - I had to actually get rid of Guice to find it. I guess Guice 3 is not supported for a reason :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm in the same situation, building a fat jar and resolving conflicts. I'll see if maybe I can use a newer Guice somehow.