# ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 83315 out of bounds for length 71658

Tags: java, guice

How do you find the root of this error:

```
com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 83315 out of bounds for length 71658
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements.forMember(StackTraceElements.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatInjectionPoint(Errors.java:712)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:684)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.format(Errors.java:555)
    at com.google.inject.CreationException.getMessage(CreationException.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:396)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:485)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:837)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Throwable.java:768)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:659)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:725)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:174)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:199)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:95)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:979)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:1006)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1117)
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:311)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:193)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:641)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:641)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:202)
    at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:408)
    at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:507)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:63)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:143)
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1117)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 83315 out of bounds for length 71658
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$LineNumbers.<init>(LineNumbers.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements$1.apply(StackTraceElements.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements$1.apply(StackTraceElements.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 67 more
```

Comment: In your code, you are looking for an array element at index location **83315** but there are only **71658** indexes (elements) within the Array. Check your looping mechanism or whatever could possibly be requesting the index number of **83315**. It would be a lot easier if you just posted the code that is causing the Exception.

Comment: I think the idea is the OP is having trouble narrowing down the offending code from this stacktrace.

Comment: Or this? [guice-3-0-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-on-startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376420/guice-3-0-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-on-startup)

Comment: Yes Guice 4.0 solved it